# Is there a way to match any case with a parameter in a Swift Enum?

Tags: swift, enums

For example lets say I have an enum like this:

```
enum Action {
   case StepOne(action)
   case StepTwo(anotherAction)
   case StepThree(finalAction)
   ...
}
```

I want to be able to match any of those cases and access their respective parameter.

This is the syntax I'm looking at:

```
switch action {
   case let ._(subaction):
       // do something here with the subaction
   /// ... other cases
}
```

Couldn't find anything online, but it's most likely the case that I'm searching the wrong terms.

Comment: I'm afraid not. The best thing to do is to make a computed property that contains a switch, all the cases, and returns the value. From there, external clients could just access the value (regardless of the "active" case), just by calling the computed property).

Comment: In this case though, your model is a bit inverted. It'd be better to have a `Step` struct, which contains a step number (1/2/3), and an `Action` member.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://alisoftware.github.io/swift/pattern-matching/2016/03/27/pattern-matching-1/

Comment: @Alexander Oh totally agree about the enum setup, it was just a quick example for the question. My drive to accomplish this was so that I didn't have to write out each possible case since the enum can grow to an unscalable size. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can sort of do this using `Mirror`:  `Mirror(reflecting: action).children.first?.value` would get you the first associated value of whatever case it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible via reflection, not sure if it is a good solution though.
Anyway computed property on the enum is likely is what you are searching for.

## Straightforward `untyped` version

```
enum Action {
    case stepOne(String)
    case stepTwo(String)
    case stepThree(Int)
}

public protocol EVAssociatedValue { }

public extension EVAssociatedValue {
    var associatedValue: Any? {
        get {
            let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
            if let associated = mirror.children.first {
                return associated.value
            }
            print("WARNING: Enum option of \(self) does not have an associated value")
            return nil
        }
    }
}

extension Action: EVAssociatedValue { }

// test
let stepTwoAction = Action.stepTwo("Delete")
print(stepTwoAction.associatedValue ?? "No value")
```

## Type constrained version

(which under the hood uses type casting anyway)

```
enum TypedAction<T> {
    case stepOne(T)
    case stepTwo(T)
    case stepThree(T)
}

public protocol EVAssociatedTypedValue {
    associatedtype V
}

public extension EVAssociatedTypedValue {
    var associatedValue: V? {
        get {
            let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
            if let associated = mirror.children.first {
                return associated.value as? V
            }
            print("WARNING: Enum option of \(self) does not have an associated value")
            return nil
        }
    }
}

extension TypedAction: EVAssociatedTypedValue {
    typealias V = T
}
// Test:

let stepTwoTypedAction = TypedAction.stepTwo("Refine")
print(stepTwoTypedAction.associatedValue ?? "No value")
```